# Problemas con Kafka,unicode y Java

Tags: java, unicode, kafka

Estoy enviando a una cola Kafka un objeto convertido en String.

El objeto en cuestión es:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class KafkaMessage {

    private String timeStamp;

    private String traceId;

    private String level;

    private String service;

    private String domain;

    private String environment;

    private String instance;

    private String message;

}
```

El método que lo envía es:

```
private void send(String message) throws Exception {
    try {
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ApiException(e.getMessage(), INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Y en la cola de Kafka aparece tal que así:

```
"KafkaMessage{timeStamp\u003d\u00272023-07-05T08:38:29.652200009\u0027, traceId\u003d\u00272023-07-05T08:38:29.652334757\u0027, level\u003d\u0027INFO\u0027, service\u003d\u0027PRUEBA\u0027, domain\u003d\u0027il-aireuropa-mail-templates-rest--v1\u0027, environment\u003d\u0027DES-V2\u0027, instance\u003d\u002710.153.0.245:31821\u0027, message\u003d\u0027PRUEBA\u0027}"
```

¿Cómo podría hacer que no apareciera en unicode? He intentado sustituir los caracteres Y enviarlo en unicode con la StringEscapeUtils, pero sigue apareciendo en unicode los caracteres '"' y '"'.

Gracias